# Graph scaling with LaTeX - Circle becomes Ellipse

Tags: latex, pgfplots

I have the following LaTeX code that creates a graph and draws a circle. However, the circle doesn't look like a circle, rather an ellipse. I think this is because of how my graph is setup. Is there any way to keep the current look/scaling of the graph while making the circle look more like a circle(I have included an image of what it looks like below)?

```
\documentclass[14pt]{article}

\usepackage[letterpaper,bindingoffset=0.2in,%
            left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in,%
            footskip=.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
                xtick distance=10,
                ytick distance=10,
                xmin=-0.0,xmax=144,
                ymin=-0.0,ymax=144,
                grid=both,
                grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},
                major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!50},
                axis lines=middle,
                minor tick num=5,
                enlargelimits={abs=0.5},
                axis line style={latex-latex},
                ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
                xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
                ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
            ]
            
        \draw (axis cs: 70, 70) circle [radius=10];
            
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Result/Output of the above code:
[image]

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre]

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz okay, done

Comment: unrelated to the problem: you should load `hyperref` after the other packages and double check if you really want the `utf8x` option and not, say, `utf8`

Comment: ... and `14pt` does nothing for standard article class

Comment: @itsMeMoriarty a _minimal reproducible example_ as mentioned above should include your full preamble!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the `width` and `height` keys to the same value, you'll get your desired circle:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
                width=\textwidth,
                height=\textwidth,
                xtick distance=10,
                ytick distance=10,
                xmin=-0.0,xmax=144,
                ymin=-0.0,ymax=144,
                grid=both,
                grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},
                major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!50},
                axis lines=middle,
                minor tick num=5,
                enlargelimits={abs=0.5},
                axis line style={latex-latex},
                ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
                xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
                ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
            ]
            
        \draw (axis cs: 70, 70) circle [radius=10];
            
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]